# Add an 'ALL ITEMS' tab along with other dynamically created tabs Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am fairly new to android and making a view in which I am populating number of tabs based on an array of names.

I have done that successfully but I want to add an additional tab at the start of my tabs whose title will be All Items.

**Here is what I am using for dynamic tabs creation:**

```
private void tabsInit() {
        for (int l = 0; l < internalCat.size(); l++) {
            product_tabs_layout.addTab(product_tabs_layout.newTab().setText(internalCat.get(l)));
        }
        ProductPagerAdapter adapter = new ProductPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), product_tabs_layout.getTabCount(), internalCat);
        product_viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
        product_viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(product_tabs_layout));
        product_tabs_layout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                product_viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                product_viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });
    }
```

**The adapter:**

```
public class ProductPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    List<String> lstInternalCats;

    public ProductPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int mNumOfTabs, List<String> lstInternalCats) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = mNumOfTabs;
        this.lstInternalCats = lstInternalCats;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ProductsFragment().newInstance(lstInternalCats.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

**This is the output:**

[image]

What I want is an additional tabs like this:

[image]

I have tried to add the tab outside the loop and then passed tabscount+1 to the number of tabs but it gives me error.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
```

Is there a way to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above solutions did not work for me.

I solved it by adding the "ALL" manually as the first element in the the List and then added the remaining items starting from Index = 1;

This way I got the fist element as ALL tab and rest of them as I wanted.

Code:

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(1);
internalCat.add(0, "All");
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
   internalCat.add(index.get(), array.getString(i));
   index.getAndIncrement();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just don't have element "All" array as I assume. So, even if you write `internalCat.size() + 1` it won't be there. You should add it manually like this:

```
product_tabs_layout.addTab(product_tabs_layout.newTab().setText("All"));
for (int l = 0; l < internalCat.size(); l++) {
    product_tabs_layout.addTab(product_tabs_layout.newTab().setText(internalCat.get(l)));
}
```

In such case, you will add tab "All" and after that all other items from the array and will never get `IndexOutOfBoundException`

Answer (score 0):

Update the for loop with this part of code

`for (int l = 0; l < internalCat.size()-1; l++) { product_tabs_layout.addTab(product_tabs_layout.newTab().setText(internalCat.get(l))); }`